# Classpath resources inside one-jar packaged via sbt

Tags: jar, classloader, sbt, onejar

I have a project that is build using SBT which packages a single jar using the one-jar plugin. That project contains a bunch of json files in src/main/resources/fixture which I used to access via

```
new java.io.File(App.getClass.getResource("/fixture").getFile
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work any longer since no Resource is returned. I think one-jar uses a special classloading mechanism? Whats the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

> I think one-jar uses a special classloading mechanism?

Yes, this must be true since there is no **standardized** way to load classes that packaged into *dependency jar* that is in turn packaged into your *application jar*. This usually is implemented with additional classloader trickery.

Loading resources when using One-JAR is [documented here](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/index.php?page=details&file=resources).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the resource docs. I finally got it working. Of the 3 potential locations, my resources were in the main/main.jar. My intention was to get the directory (File) packaged into the main.jar using MainClass.getClass.getResource("/dirname") and to iterate it's children (Files). That didn't work out. I was however able to load the contents of each file in that directory by using MainClass.getClass.getResourceAsStream("/dirname/filename.json")

Answer (score 2):

one-jar packages your resources under the `main` dir in the output jar. when using sbt, I find it best to configure the packaging of resources myself.
usually, I would do something like this:

```scala
unmanagedResources in Compile := Seq() //we don't want to add resources from "src/main/resources" to inner jar

mappings in oneJar += (file("src/main/resources/filename.json"),"path/to/resource/in/onejar")
```

so your resource `filename.json` will be packaged where you want it in the one-jar jar. 
when you want the resource at runtime, simply use:

```scala
Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("path/to/your/resource")
```

have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288585/producing-two-separate-jars-for-sources-and-resources-with-package-in-sbt/22296675#22296675). it may help with how to package all the resources under `src/main/resources`...

Answer (score 0):

I found that Spring's core PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver can do this. It's also can find files according to pattern.

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
resolver.getResources("classpath*:some/package/name/**/*.xml");
```