# Producing two separate jars for sources and resources with package in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Because of the large size of some resource files, I'd like `sbt package` to create 2 jar files at the same time, e.g. `project-0.0.1.jar` for the classes and `project-0.0.1-res.jar` for the resources.

Is this doable?

[SOLUTION] based on the answer below thanks to @gilad-hoch

1) `unmanagedResources in Compile := Seq()`

Now it's just classes in the default jar.

2)

```
val packageRes = taskKey[File]("Produces a jar containing only the resources folder")
packageRes := {
  val jarFile = new File("target/scala-2.10/" + name.value + "_" + "2.10" + "-" + version.value + "-res.jar")
  sbt.IO.jar(files2TupleRec("", file("src/main/resources")), jarFile, new java.util.jar.Manifest)
  jarFile
}

def files2TupleRec(pathPrefix: String, dir: File): Seq[Tuple2[File, String]] = {
  sbt.IO.listFiles(dir) flatMap {
    f => {
      if (f.isFile) Seq((f, s"${pathPrefix}${f.getName}"))
      else files2TupleRec(s"${pathPrefix}${f.getName}/", f)
    }
  }
}

(packageBin in Compile) <<= (packageBin in Compile) dependsOn (packageRes)
```

Now when I do "sbt package", both the default jar and a resource jar are produced at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to not include the resources in the main jar, you could simply add the following line:

```
unmanagedResources in Compile := Seq()
```

to add another jar, you could define a new task. it would generally be something like that:
use [sbt.IO](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.0/api/index.html#sbt.IO%24) `jar` method to create the jar.
you could use something like:

```
def files2TupleRec(pathPrefix: String, dir: File): Seq[Tuple2[File,String]] = {
    sbt.IO.listFiles(dir) flatMap {
        f => {
            if(f.isFile) Seq((f,s"${pathPrefix}${f.getName}"))
            else files2TupleRec(s"${pathPrefix}${f.getName}/",f)
        }
    }
}
files2TupleRec("",file("path/to/resources/dir")) //usually src/main/resources
```

or use the built-in methods from [`Path`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html#relative-to-a-directory) to create the `sources: Traversable[(File, String)]` required by the `jar` method.
that's basically the whole deal...